# Cannot get the result of the Backbone model fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My model urlRoot:

```
    urlRoot: function() {
    if (this.id != null ) {
        return 'notes/' + this.id; 
    } else return 'notes';
}
```

Function:

```
window.show_note = function (note_id) {
var note = new Memo.Models.Note([], { id: note_id });
note.fetch({
    success: function (collection, note, response) {
        var noteObj = collection.get("0");
        var noteView = new Memo.Views.FullNote( {model: noteObj }, {flag: 0 } );    
        $('.content').html(noteView.render().el);
    }
});}
```

{ id: note_id } - I post this to server to get note by id
I want to do 'set' or 'get' functions on model 'note' after note.fetch in a callback function - success, but only I have is error: 'Uncaught TypeError: note.set is not a function'.

If I do this way: 'var noteObj = collection.get("0");'
I get that I need but I still can`t use get or set.

Comment: Dont use the same name `var note = ...` and `success: function (collection, note, response) {` ! but what is your problem precisly ?

Comment: this- Uncaught TypeError: note.set is not a function

Comment: there is no `note.set` in your sample so when it occur ?

Comment: I just delete it cus it makes issue

Comment: maybe you can add this part of code ?

Comment: Is `Memo.Models.Note` a model or a collection? Because urlRoot is a model property, but you use `Memo.Models.Note` as a collection.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `urlRoot` to:

```
urlRoot: '/notes'
```

And backbone will figure out that it needs to add the `id` to the url. ([docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot))

Assuming `Memo.Models.Note` is a model and not a collection, the above snippet should be like this:

```
window.show_note = function(note_id) {
    var note = new Memo.Models.Note({ id: note_id });

    note.fetch({
        success: function (model, response, options) {
            var noteView = new Memo.Views.FullNote({
                model: model
            }, {flag: 0 });

            $('.content').html(noteView.render().el);
        }
    });
};
```

Note the argument passed to `new Memo.Models.Note`. A backbone model constructor takes two arguments: `attributes` and `options` ([docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor)) as opposed to a collection, which takes `models` and `options` ([docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor)). So you'll want to add the hash with the `id` property as the first argument.

Also note the function signature of the `success` callback. For a model the `success` callback takes three arguments: `model`, `response` and `options` ([docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch)). You'll be interested in the `model` argument because that is the fetched backbone model. `response` is the raw response data.

I hope my assumptions are right and this is the answer you are looking for.